# Alamofire wrong order of JSON response

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I use Alamofire to populate a TableView.
This is an extract of my code:

```
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
        Alamofire.request(api_url5).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                    self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    print (api_url5)
                    print (self.arrRes)
                }
                if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                    self.tblDetail.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

The request has a "sort" parameter which outputs the right order in Postman. But the items in the table are in the wrong order and the output I receive with `print (self.arrRes)` too.

How can I keep the order I get from my API?

Order in Postman:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "we": "text",
            "de": "text",
            "se": "text",
            "ve": "text",
            "qe": "text",
            "ne": "text"
        },
{
            "we": "wer",
            "de": "wer",
            "se": "wer",
            "ve": "wer",
            "qe": "wer",
            "ne": "wer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Order in the console:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
            "we": "wer",
            "de": "wer",
            "se": "wer",
            "ve": "wer",
            "qe": "wer",
            "ne": "wer"
        },
        {
            "we": "text",
            "de": "text",
            "se": "text",
            "ve": "text",
            "qe": "text",
            "ne": "text"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: @Francis They could be getting reversed, can you try getting it to return more than 2 items?

Comment: @TPN1994 even if I return more than 2 items, the order is wrong. But without a pattern, just mixed up...

Comment: Could you use `JSONSerialization` on `responseData.result.value` instead of SwiftyJSON? Just to check if it's the Request or the SwiftyJSON the culprit. Also could you print `swiftyJsonVar` too? Maybe ``swiftyJsonVar["data"]` to be sure?

Comment: Add the sort parameter to your request

Comment: @Larme the printed swiftyJsonVar has the wrong order too.

Comment: @Sam_M which option do I have to use to keep the original order?

Comment: @Francis What option are you using in postman that you see the right order?

Comment: And the `String.init(data:responseData.result.value encoding:.utf8)`? "The request has a "sort" parameter ", just read that. Do you mean that `api_url5` has some param there? Which ones?

Comment: @Sam_M I add a sort parameter to my API request.

Comment: @Larme With sort parameter I mean I add "&sort=true" to my request

Comment: And in POSTMAN, is the URL the same then?

Comment: @Larme yes, the URLs are the same...

Comment: You should check the results with one the native networking functions (such as `URLSession.shared.dataTask`) and the native JSON deserialiser, `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` to help pinpointing the issue.

Comment: @DávidPásztor then the order is the right one

Comment: Then you should just pinpoint the issue to either `SwiftyJSON` or `Alamofire` and submit a GitHub issue under their project, since this seems to be a bug rather than a programming error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the sort parameter that you are using in postman to your api request:

```
Alamofire.request(api_url5, parameters: ["sort":"true"]).responseJSON {
```

Comment: Does this work if my api_url5 is: http://myserver/api/v1/api.php?...request...&sort=true ?

Comment: @Francis Well if you have already put it in the url there's no need to put it in parameters... Is this request absolutely identical to the one you are using with postman?

Comment: it is exactly the same url. Why does Alamofire mix the answer from the API?